# how to transfer animation from a No-IK animated rig to an IK-constrained rig with similar bones

Tags: animation

I have old fbx file with animations. I imported the skeleton and added IK and constrains. I wanted to copy the animation data from the old fbx to the new RIG but when I use the Non linear animation(NLA) actions to copy the animations from the old fbx file, it does reflect and it seems that the New IK constrains are preventing it to pose correctly. Any idea how to solve this? I am fairly new but I appreciate any advise and tips! H

Thanks! I love the new Blender 2.8

Comment: How is the old animations created? What you should do is to export the animation from the old controllers and not the baked animation. Reverse the an IK solution from a FK is not always possible and usually not precise.

Comment: let's say the original files are long gone and only the fbx remain

Comment: Then I would say it will be easier to do a proper rig and recreate the animations, possibly using the old armature and animation as template. Reversing IK from FK is little bit like unbreaking a glass.